# Displaying the blog entries in a Page (using get_posts to retrieve the posts)?

Tags: pages, blog

I made a page called **blog.php** which will store my blog entries, all the other pages have a custom post type called "**Page Content**" (for static content). I wanted to make a heading in this blog page which is retrieved from main loop of the current page (`the_content`), and used a `get_posts` to retrieve the blog entries.

I tried doing the opposite: using `get_posts` to get `the_content` of the current page but it retrieved `the_content` of the blog entries. (and using the main loop to retrieve the posts).

Will I have problems by using this method? Is there a better way to do this?

The desired result:
[image]

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Blog
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Prominent
 * @since Prominent 1.0
 */
get_header(); ?>
<div class="shadow-top">
 <!-- Shadow at the top of the slider -->
</div>
<div id="intro2">
 <div class="container">
  <?php // Start the Main Loop
  if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="content">
     <h2><?php the_content(); ?></h2>
   </div><!-- .content -->
   <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!-- #slider-wrapper -->
 </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #featured -->
<div class="shadow-bottom">
 <!-- Shadow at the bottom of the slider -->
</div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="container">
  <?php // Create custom loop
  $custom_posts = get_posts(); // Defaults args fetch posts starting with the most recent ?>
  <?php foreach( $custom_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
   <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
   <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyten' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?> </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #content-bottom -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) instead of `get_posts()` and you should be able to use the posts as in the normal loop.

Edit - don't forget to reset the default query with `wp_reset_query()` before using `query_posts` or I believe the function will again return the page contents.

Comment: the code above works. I get blog entries using `get_posts()` and the main loop gets the page title and content. So what would be the difference if I use `query_posts()`?

Comment: @janoChen not much of a difference as far as I can tell, just that using query_posts on its own makes posts behave like in the usual loop, so it asves you a few attributions & calls to `setup_postdata`